# Implement a mapping between different types (bool? and enum) using DataContract

Tags: c#, .net, datacontract

I am using `DataContract` to serialize/deserialize objects on the user's machine. So basically a save/load scenario.

I have a `DataContract` which had an ordered `DataMember` of type `bool?` and now I need to change it to an `Enum`. It's ordered because one of the serializers is [protobuf-net](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net).

How it looks now:

```
[DataContract]
public class Result
{ 
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public bool? Accepted { get; set; }
}
```

It needs to be:

```
public enum ResultDecisionStatus
{
    Accepted, //// map as 'true' for 'bool?'
    Rejected, //// map as 'false' for 'bool?'
    Neutral, //// new
    Unknown //// map as 'null' for 'bool?'
}

[DataContract]
public class Result
{
    [DataMember(Order = 4?)]   //// I assume ordering might have to change
    public ResultDecisionStatus DecisionStatus { get; set; }
}
```

I implemented the following which seems to me to be *hacky* but seems to work. I kept `Accepted` in the same ordering and changed it to `private` and set a variable to map it to the new `Enum` upon deserialization. Is this good design? It feels weird.

```
[DataContract]
public class Result
{
    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public ResultDecisionStatus DecisionStatus { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    private bool? Accepted { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 1003)]
    private bool AcceptedToDecisionStatusMapped { get; set; }

    [OnDeserialized]
    private void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (!AcceptedToDecisionStatusMapped)
        {
            switch(Accepted) 
            {
                case true:
                    DecisionStatus = ResultDecisionStatus.Accepted;
                    break;
                case false:
                    DecisionStatus = ResultDecisionStatus.Rejected;
                    break;
                case null:
                    DecisionStatus = ResultDecisionStatus.Unknown;
                    break;
            }
            AcceptedToDecisionStatusMapped = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Question:** Is there any proper way to implement a mapping between types for ordered `DataContracts` without keeping old members and adding extra mapping properties for each version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Result
{ 
    private ResultDecisionStatus? _decisionStatus;

    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public bool? Accepted { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public ResultDecisionStatus DecisionStatus 
    { 
        get
        {
            if (_decisionStatus.HasValue)
            {
                return _decisionStatus.Value;
            }
            else if (Accepted.HasValue)
            {
                return Accepted.Value 
                    ? ResultDecisionStatus.Accepted 
                    : ResultDecisionStatus.Rejected;
            }
            else
            {
                return ResultDecisionStatus.Unknown;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            _decisionStatus = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This should basically allow data using the old contract and the new to interoperate. It'd get weird if both `3` and `4` were used, but I assume it'll be either one or the other in your case.

**Update**:

See my other answer. In your case, since the boolean can map easily to the enum values, there's a simpler way. Leaving this answer for the case where someone may not have this luxury.

Comment: Oh neat, that gets rid of the mapping variable. There's probably no way of getting rid of `Accepted` is there?

Comment: Yeah, not without breaking B/C.

Comment: See my other answer; that should be a better way if it works, and it introduces no new fields.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `bool` and `int32` are compatible in protobuf, so you could do this:

```
public enum ResultDecisionStatus
{
    Rejected = 0, // will catch old boolean false values
    Accepted = 1, // will catch old boolean true values
    Neutral = 2 // new
}

[DataContract]
public class Result
{ 
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public ResultDecisionStatus? DecisionStatus { get; set; } 
}
```

Just use `null` to stand for `Unknown`.

Comment: This looks really simple, but it doesn't seem to work for me. I keep getting everything back as `null`. I have viewmodels which wrap `Results` and have converters from the `DecisionStatus` to an image source and when I debug the converter, all values are comming in as `null`. The deserialization right now is done with `XmlSerializer`. Didn't want to get into specifics, but I have multiple possible deserializers based on previous software versions. Your other answer worked perfectly. I'll keep trying but if i can't succeed, I'll just accept your other answer.

Comment: Yeah debugged it right out of deserialization, all values coming back as `null`. Might have to do with the serializer?

Comment: I see, this probably wouldn't work if in some cases you use `XmlSerializer` and in others `protobuf-net` since there won't be automatic coercion between bool and enums in the case of XML. So the other answer is probably better for your case, and this would be better if it was just protobuf.